# How to deserialize the following xml in silverlight in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, xml-deserialization

```xml
<SampleType xmlns="xxx:yyy:zzz">
    <Timestamp xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc">2012-03-07T04:47:07Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc">Success</Ack>
    <CorrelationID xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc">ef1ee378dd51</CorrelationID>
    <EncryptionDetails xsi:type="ns:MEPEncryptionDetailsType">
        <Type xsi:type="xs:string">SHA1</Type>
        <Key xsi:type="xs:string"></Key>
    </EncryptionDetails>
</SampleType>
```

When I tried to deserialize this XML, I got the following error "'xsi' is an undeclared namespace."
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to find the string `xmlns:xsi` somewhere. Maybe it is defined at the beginning of the full xml-document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your XML file includes a definition for the `xsi` namespace alias. Add the following attribute to the root element in you XML:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Comment: i can't control the response tho. I figured this by using XMLReaderSetting class. Thanks.

Comment: @sunxin8086:  Then you need to have words with people that do have "control of the response" and tell them that the XML they are sending is unacceptable. They should not be including an undefined xml:ns alais.   Your only other choice is to adjust the xml string before loading it.